# Как прикрепить к сообщению(от бота) видео с помощью питона или как пользоваться attachment в вк

Tags: python, вконтакте, бот

Недавно решил написать бота-страницу(пользователь) для вк(с технологией лонг полл), *писал и писал*, захотел сделать команду ор, не получилось, так как не умею пользоваться attachment(не понял куда вставлять и юзать), научите пж.
После компиляции выдаёт ошибку NameError: name 'video..._..' is not defined

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возьмите идентификатор видео в кавычки:

`attachment="video-1111111111"`

И никогда больше не прикладывайте в вопрос код картинкой - его нужно прикладывать только текстом.